# Use Content/Markup in custom-element outside of router-view

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Jolly good evening. In my Aurelia-App I'm looking for the best way to copy/move **markup** from my subpage to an element (module) outside of the router-view-container. It is fairly easy to send strings/json via the event-Emitter and to render it within the outside-module, but how do I achieve this with working Markup?

There are a couple of reasons why I'm interested in this solution, the most intuitive would be to use the markup in an overlay that can't for styling reasons be positioned inside (in this case) the main-div.

#### app.html

```
<template>
  <require from="./module"></require>
  <module></module> <-- Show (specific) contents from router-view in here.
  <div class="main">
      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Do [viewports](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/9) solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm looking for a more flexible, component-based solution that I can trigger from within the Subpage.